# please help identify the temperature sensor on this PCB

Tags: sensor, identification, temperature

The PCB is the wireless (outside) sender unit for an inside/outside thermometer. I want to create a temperature probe from this PCB so that I can measure a temperature in a very specific place.
I need help identifying the temperature sensor component on the PCB. I have had no luck pinning it down with freeze spray. Maybe it's the pair of transistors?

(you can view the images at high resolution by doing right-click > view image)
[image: PCB1]
[image: PCB2]

Following on from the accepted answer (thanks!), I tried moving the component out into a probe.

[image: modified PCB]
[image: probe in hot water tank port]

Temperature agrees with my current wired solution.
[image: probe working]

Comment: A schematic would help, even with the IC blank.

Comment: And one of the transistors is for the DC/DC converter, the other is for the transmitter.

Comment: It's almost certainly that cylindrical object under the IC. If you can provide the IC markings (they are invisible in the photo) the part number can probably be Googled.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  The shiny metallic cylinder looks more like a crystal to me.  It even has got a pair of capacitors.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - That was my thought originally. But then what is in the can at bottom center of the upper photo?

Comment: It's a crystal (for an oscillator; perhaps for the RF transmitter). The thin one (top photo, upper middle portion) is perhaps a 32768 crystal for a real time clock.

Comment: If you're building your own temperature probe, just get a thermistor or other sensor new from e.g. Digikey, you can get stuff like the TC77 for 99 cents, others for even cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following 4 principles of temperature sensors are most common: thermistor, thermocouple, resistive temperature detector (RTD), silicon bandgap.

- Thermocouple and RTD.  Not visible on the photos.
  In addition, they are rarely found in consumer goods that measure around human temperature range.  Thermocouples and RTDs require signal conditioning and excitation circuitry, which increases cost.
  *prediction: Unlikely*
- [Silicon bandgap temperature sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_bandgap_temperature_sensor) are found in consumer goods sometimes.  They are packaged like transistors or ICs.  They may be embedded inside microcontrollers or ASICs.
  *prediction: Plausible*
- [Thermistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) produce a strong signal and don't require much signal conditioning.    It's a cost-effective way of measuring temperature in the human range.  These are used in consumer goods.
  *prediction: Plausible*

[image]

Hit with chill spray, see what happens.

Comment: I vote for the thermistor, too, because it looks exactly like an NTC we used. It seems to build a voltage divider with the R to the left, supplied by the IC via the two tracks with test points. The track left of the R is the read out voltage.

Comment: See the two test points near it? I think they are a dead giveaway that there is something of interest.