# Help identifying a temperature sensor on PCB

Tags: sensor, identification, temperature

I have this PCB which is the motherboard of my pellet stove. It is reading a value "T Board" which is the temperature of the board. Now it's reading faulty values (86°C at ambient temperature) and the stove won't work normally.

I disassembled the motherboard, disconnected everything, put it on power and I can still see the temperature on the remote control and make it change using a hair dryer to heat the board. It will not change much however, up to 91°C, may be because of the faulty sensor.

The problem is, I failed to find which component is the sensor. After some research on the subject, I think it might be a thermistor but the one I found at the bottom of the board (blue near the transformer) seems to be just for the power part (it wont change the reading if I heat only this component.)

If it is an SMD thermistor, is there any tips to distinguish it from resistors/capacitors?

Full board picture:

[image]

Zoom on the part that seems the most sensitive to the hair dryer:

[image]

**Update 1:**

Following suggestions in comments, here are the things checked:

- RTC component is MCP79411, it does not have a temperature sensor according to datasheet.
- 8 pin component near ATmega is labeled 33064, an undervoltage circuit according to what I found on the internet.
- TO92 component on the top is labeled 7333-A, it's a LDO regulator. Second TO92 (between transformer and radiator) is not visible, but it goes to a connector labeled "Vacuometro" so I guess it's not a temp sensor.
- I traced ADC pins of the ATmega (ports F) but I couldn't find anything useful. Of course I could have missed something.
- I also tried moving around the hot tip of my soldering iron, but I failed to trigger any temperature change on the remote control. Very disappointing since hair dryer will still trigger a 5°C variation.

Comment: Could be a temp sensor in the RTC chip? Could be one of the TO92 transistor like devices? Trace the circuits on the ADC pins of the mega64.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you for suggestions, they all made a lot of sense. Sadly I couldn't find anything useful. I will probably get a replacement board next week.

Comment: Does the atmega64 have an internal temp sensor?

Comment: @Nicolas  SW2 has writing "KTY/NTC" next to it, and it's in the "NTC" position.  "NTC" probably stands for "negative temperature coefficient [thermistor]".  The thermistor may be nearby, although I can't spot one in the photo.

Comment: @Nicolas  similar "where's thermistor" question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/205789/7036